# Binding /var during installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, filesystem, ssd, fstab

I want to install an SSD into my desktop PC, putting there the root and other folders like /etc. What I don't want to put there is /var, because I work with databases pretty often. So, what I want to do is I want to bind a directory on my HDD to /var, kinda like this:

`/mnt/hdd/var /var bind <...>`

I'd like to know:

1. Is it possible to do during the installation?
2. Is there any reason why it could be bad?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do during the installation?

No. That is something you need to do after installation. Possible method: you could add the commands for that to a "preseed" file as "post" installation actions.

> Is there any reason why it could be bad?

Bad? No. But I would not expect it myself.

If all you are concerned about is databases in /var/ the more logical method would be to move the database storage settings. MySQL has a setting for where it stores it database (`datadir` in `my.cnf`. So does Postgres (`data_directory` in `postgres.conf`).

Comment: Well, for what I know /var also holds logs and other data that may cause SSD wear. So I'd like to get rid of it entirely.
If I do it post-install, I'd need to move the entire /var directory, right? Most likely via some kind of external distro even.

Comment: You can just do a "mv /var/* /mnt/hdd/var/*" and then bind it (with all services stopped ;) from the current release)